# Understanding Properties of Probability Used in a Paper

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm working through a proof in a paper and I could use some help clarifying some probability properties.

Consider some operator $T:D \to R$ where both $D$ and $R$ are Hilbert spaces. Let $r_{i}$ for $i \in [1,N]$ be random normal vectors.

In one proof they said

$P(\underset{i \in 1,...,N}{\max} ||Tr_i||_R > ||T||) \leq N P(||Tr||_R > ||T||)$

Where $r$ is some new random normal vector.

In another proof they said
$P(\underset{i \in 1,...,N}{\max} ||Tr_i||_R < ||T||) = P(||Tr||_R < ||T||)^ N $
Again, where $r$ is some new random normal vector.

1. So can we assume that the sum of the probabilities is going to be greater than the multiplication of them always? This seems to be true to me but I just wanted to confirm it.
2. Why can we just say that the probability of all test vectors being smaller some value can be written like this with a new random vector $r$? I was just confused on why some new random one could be used without any specifications of it satisfying the max requirement.

I'm a bit rusty in probability so if anyone could elaborate on this I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: For 1.), note that any two probabilities are just real numbers $0\leq x, y \leq 1$, so $x \leq 1 \implies xy \leq y$, and $0 \leq x \implies y \leq x + y$, therefore $xy \leq y \leq x + y$. Therefore the sum of the two probabilities is greater than their product, and you can apply induction for any countable product and sum of probabilities.

Comment: @tiral thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first inequality is a consequence of the [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality). An identical way of writing
$$\max_{i \in 1,...,N} \|Tr_i\|_R > \|T\|$$
is to say that
$$\|Tr_1\|_R > \|T\| \text{ OR } \|Tr_2\|_R > \|T\|\text{ OR } ... \text{ OR } \|Tr_N\|_R > \|T\|$$
Since these are equivalent statements we have
\begin{align}
  &P\left ( \max_{i \in 1,...,N} \|Tr_i\|_R > \|T\| \right ) \\
  &= P \left ( \|Tr_1\|_R > \|T\| \text{ OR } \|Tr_2\|_R > \|T\|\text{ OR } ... \text{ OR } \|Tr_N\|_R > \|T\| \right ).
\end{align}
Now by the union bound we have
\begin{align}
  &P \left ( \|Tr_1\|_R > \|T\| \text{ OR } \|Tr_2\|_R > \|T\|\text{ OR } ... \text{ OR } \|Tr_N\|_R > \|T\| \right ) \\
  &\leq \sum_{i=1}^N P(\|Tr_i\|_R > \|T\|)
\end{align}
Now if $r_1,...,r_n,r$ are all identically distributed, then the random scalars $\|Tr_1\|_R,...,\|Tr_N\|_R,\|Tr\|_R$ are also identically distributed and therefore for every $i=1,...,N$ it holds that
$$P(\|Tr_i\|_R > \|T\|) = P(\|Tr\|_R > \|T\|).$$
Plugging this into the summation above gives
$$\sum_{i=1}^N P(\|Tr_i\|_R > \|T\|) = \sum_{i=1}^N P(\|Tr\|_R > \|T\|) = NP(\|Tr\|_R > \|T\|).$$
The key reason we can do this latter part is because $r$ has the *same distribution* as every $r_i$. Combining the chain of inequalities we have shown
$$P\left ( \max_{i \in 1,...,N} \|Tr_i\|_R > \|T\| \right )  \leq NP(\|Tr\|_R > \|T\|).$$

---

The second inequality uses similar ideas but is a bit different. An identical way of writing
$$\max_{i \in 1,...,N} \|Tr_i\|_R < \|T\|$$
is to say that
$$\|Tr_1\|_R < \|T\| \text{ AND } \|Tr_2\|_R < \|T\|\text{ AND } ... \text{ AND } \|Tr_N\|_R < \|T\|$$
notice that we are now using AND instead of OR, and $<$ instead of $>$.

Since these statements are equivalent we have
\begin{align}
   &P\left ( \max_{i \in 1,...,N} \|Tr_i\|_R < \|T\| \right ) \\
   &= P \left ( \|Tr_1\|_R < \|T\| \text{ AND } \|Tr_2\|_R < \|T\|\text{ AND } ... \text{ AND } \|Tr_N\|_R < \|T\| \right )
\end{align}
Now I believe that it is implicitly assumed that $r_1,...,r_N$ are *independent* which implies that $\|Tr_1\|_R,...,\|Tr_N\|_R$ are also independent. By definition of independence this means that
\begin{align}
   &P \left ( \|Tr_1\|_R < \|T\| \text{ AND } \|Tr_2\|_R < \|T\|\text{ AND } ... \text{ AND } \|Tr_N\|_R < \|T\| \right ) \\
   &= \prod_{i=1}^N P(\|Tr_i\|_R < \|T\|)
\end{align}
Now again if $r_i$ and $r$ have the same distribution then for $i=1,...,N$ we have
$$P(\|Tr_i\|_R < \|T\|) = P(\|Tr\|_R < \|T\|).$$
Plugging this in above gives
$$\prod_{i=1}^N P(\|Tr_i\|_R < \|T\|) = \prod_{i=1}^N P(\|Tr\|_R < \|T\|) = P(\|Tr\|_R < \|T\|)^N$$
and combining the chain of equalities we have shown that
$$P\left ( \max_{i \in 1,...,N} \|Tr_i\|_R < \|T\| \right ) = P(\|Tr\|_R < \|T\|)^N.$$

In this case we needed BOTH that the $r_i$ are distributed the same as $r$ and that the $r_i$ are independent.

Comment: This was such a well written, clear answer. Thank you! This fully cleared things up for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: Happy to be of service!